# Loop or Wildcard to integrate through JQuery UI Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am calling the content of a PHP file via AJAX similar to this:

NEW.PHP

```
$output =  '<p>Date: <input type="text" id="field_1"></p>
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="field_6"></p>
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="field_7"></p>';

echo $output;
```

The inputs are generated dynamically depending on options the user selected.  In this case, field_1 and field_7 would be date picker fields and field_6 would be a standard text box.

In my main page, the jQuery success handler looks like this:

```
success: function(result){
    jQuery('#div-custom').html(result).show();                
    jQuery("#div-custom").find("#field_1,#field_7" ).datepicker({
              numberOfMonths: 3,
              showButtonPanel: true
    });
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the number of date picker fields is dynamic and the field number field_X can be different.  Is there a way to make this `find("#field_1,#field_7")` dynamic or use a wildcard?  I can change my PHP code so that, for example, all date picker fields are called date_X and other fields are field_X.

In that case, I'd like to do something like `find("#date_*)` but don't know if that's possible.  I'm definitely not strong with Javascript.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `class` as you can use the same class on multiple items unlike `id`s

`<p>Date: <input type="text" class="cal" id="field_X"></p>`

`jQuery("#div-custom").find(".cal" ).datepicker({`

Comment: Hello!  Thank you for this - that worked perfectly.  Only weird issue that it causes is the field label isn't appearing.  Here's the HTML/PHP code:`'<p class="fieldLabel">'.$LABEL.':</p><input name="field_'.$custom_id.'" id="field_'.$custom_id.'" type="text" class="inputTextDatePicker" placeholder="" value="'.$fieldValue.'" maxlength="10" /><br />';`  If I view the PHP page directly, the fieldLabel appears.  But when it renders on the main page via AJAX, it is missing....?!

Comment: Looks like it was just a CSS conflict with jQuery UI.  All good.  REALLY appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you rely completely on the ids, then you can use 'starts with' selector on the input elements.

```
$("#div-custom input[id^='field']").datepicker({
```

This would be applicable on all input with ids starts with 'field' within a div with id ='div-custom'.